# 3D chart in three.js

Tags: three.js, forex

I would love to create a 3D chart in three.js. For example: in 3d http://tinyurl.com/m3q3d7w
The source code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/C5GZnxcV

The smallest value in the stock exchange graph is 0,0001 they call it 'Point'.

There are 1 and 4 point move in most of these graphs, but if I would like to display these values in a 3D window, I can barely see them they are just too small.
That's why I increased all the size with *5000, but it doesn't work either. How can I make them bigger, so the values are more visible?

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/3v3GxOt.png

Comment: 2d chart example: http://www.investing.com/currencies/eur-usd-chart

Comment: Is the screenshot what you already have? If so, just move the camera to the position that gives the perspective/angle you want. If you put this in a jsfiddle it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I have jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/naburus/y8ANC/2/

Comment: I don't really have an idea of what your problem is, but you may want to look at the call to drawCandle(). It seems to me that you should be sending 7 arguments to the function.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite the code so it can be more understandable.

Comment: Problem solved, i don't need more help. Ty

Comment: @user3841623 could you post your source code on jsfiddle.net ? For me does not work.

Comment: @Rubidium Could you post answer??